# esri javascript asynchronous print

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api

## The Setup:

I am using the [javascript API v. 2.8 from ESRI](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/printtask.htm), which itself uses the **dojo toolkit v. 1.6**. I have the [ArcGIS Server v. 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005z2000000) running on Windows in Amazon's EC2.

I can successfully execute a PrintTask with javascript that POSTs JSON to my server, which runs a process and returns a PDF to the client-browser. But this request is *synchronous* and can take a minute or two, causing **Heroku** to timeout with an H12 error.

## The Problem:

When I toggle the [ ] Asynchronous checkbox to **ON** on the ArcGIS server, my PrintTask returns:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Error performing execute operation","details":[]}}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Does anybody have any examples or experience running an asynchronous print task on ArcGIS server?

The javascript for the printTask is below. Is there a way to re-write this javascript to be more asynchronous, or "non-blocking"?

## The code

*(stripped down for brevity)*

```
dojo.require("esri.tasks.PrintTask");

function Print() {
  var printTool = this;

  this.executePrint = function(){
    var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
    params.map = map;
    params.template = selectedTemplate;
    printTask = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(printUrl, {async: true});
    printTask.execute(params, printTool.printComplete, printTool.printError);
  };

  this.printComplete = function(result){
    dojo.place("<div><a href='" + result.url + "'></a></div>", printForm, "last");
  };

  this.printError = function(err){
    dojo.byId("printJob").innerHTML = err;
  };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling the print task, if the task is async, the call will need to be to the printTask.submitJob method, not the execute method.

See
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_gp_running.html

Comment: As a note for others; submitJob gets called when setting async to true in PrintParameters.  Otherwise, when synchronous, the execute() function is called.  Your JavaScript code will still make a call to printTask.execute, but using Developer Tools, you will notice that the URL shows that submitJob is called by printTask (ie. arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/submitJob).

Answer (score 0):

If its a page load driven event use `dojo.addOnLoad` or `dojo.ready`, depending on your version.

If you're calling `Print` from a user event (e.g. click) easiest way out is to schedule it to run, when idle

```
function whenIdle(ptr_fun) {
    setTimeout(ptr_fun, 1);
}
whenIdle(Print);
```

Comment: Upgrading from ESRI's Javascript API version 2.8 to 3.2 fixed the problem. It seems like the {async: true} parameter did not make a difference on 2.8, but does on 3.2.